# Loading bean in view slows app down

Tags: android, android-annotations

In my app I am using [AndroidAnnotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations). In a certain View (@EViewGroup) I am loading a bean using @Bean. The problem is that everytime an item is added to the view it loads that bean into the view. When I have 10 items in my view the bean is loaded 10 times and slows down the app. How can I do this in a better way so the app won't be slowed down everytime the list items are loading?

Comment: Is it possible to move the loading of that bean in the background?
Are you sure that you're using that library in the correct manner?

Comment: I tried to find if that was possible but I don't think it's possible.

Comment: What are you doing in the bean initialisation, so creating those beans is so slow?

Comment: Nothing special, I even created a new empty bean and that also took a lot of work. I think it's just because the bean get's loaded a lot of times in a short timespan. I now refactored my app so I don't have to use the bean in the view but it would be helpful in the future if beans could be loaded in the background.